# Combing Tables that are Side-by-side

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have data set up in a terrible way (this was done before my time) and I need to consolidate it across ranges, sheets, and files.

Here's an example. I am trying to append all three of these ranges into a single table, with a column labeling which category the line item is from.
[image]

Comment: What are you using to correlate a row in table 1 with a row in table 2? Just the line number? You could try this to add a row number to each table then simply join them all one to one https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-add-a-Serial-Number-or-Row-Number-Column-in-Power-BI/td-p/52998 PS. If you _are_ joining on row number, prepare for things to go bad. You should join on something more reliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to deal with your example sheet. I started with an excel sheet called Sheet1, like below:

[image]

Then, in another workbook, I created a Power Query query with this M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("MyPath\MyFile.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(Sheet1_Sheet),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Transposed Table", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Split Table by 3 Nested" = Table.Split(#"Removed Blank Rows",3),
    #"Inserted Row Nested" = List.Transform(#"Split Table by 3 Nested", each Table.InsertRows(_, Table.RowCount(_),{Record.FromList(List.Repeat({null},Table.ColumnCount(_)),Table.ColumnNames(_))})),
    #"Filled Category Down Nested" = List.Transform(#"Inserted Row Nested", each Table.FillDown(_,{"Column1"})),
    #"Transposed Tables Nested" = List.Transform(#"Filled Category Down Nested", each Table.Transpose(_)),
    #"Removed Blank Rows Nested" = List.Transform(#"Transposed Tables Nested", each Table.SelectRows(_, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))),
    #"Filled Category Down Nested2" = List.Transform(#"Removed Blank Rows Nested", each Table.FillDown(_,{"Column4"})),
    #"Removed First LIne Nested" = List.Transform(#"Filled Category Down Nested2", each Table.Skip(_,1)),
    #"Promoted First Line Nested" = List.Transform(#"Removed First LIne Nested", each Table.PromoteHeaders(_, [PromoteAllScalars=true])),
    #"Renamed Category Column Nested" = List.Transform(#"Promoted First Line Nested", each Table.RenameColumns(_,{{Table.ColumnNames(_){3}, "Category"}})),
    #"Combined Nested Tables" = Table.Combine(#"Renamed Category Column Nested"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Combined Nested Tables",{"Category", "Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

To get this result:

[image]

Most of the transformative work is done within nested tables via List.Transform.